# Working with structs and pointers in C to make a Binary tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree that stores Strings in alphabetical order.
I.e. if one node is "Computer" and a new node is added, say "Bat" then "Bat" will become the left hand child of "Computer". Similarly "Driver" would be the right hand child of "Computer" if it was added immediately after.

This is the code i have so far. (It compiles with no errors or warnings)

I have a feeling the problem is in the insertNode function but I'm a bit out of my depth and don't really know.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCHARS 100

struct node{
    char word[MAXCHARS];
    int length;
    int count;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
int copyString(char *in, char *out){
    int i = 0;
    while(in[i] != '\0'){
        out[i] = in[i];
        i++;
    }
    out[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int compareString(char *s1, char *s2){
    int i, j;
    int s1length = strlen(s1);
    int s2length = strlen(s2);
    int lengthToUse;
    if(s1length < s2length){
        lengthToUse = s1length;
    } else{
        lengthToUse = s2length;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < lengthToUse; i++){
        if(s1[i] - s2[i] != 0){
            return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
        } else{
            if (i ==  lengthToUse -1 && s1[i] - s2[i] == 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }    
    }
}

void insertNode(struct node **t, char *s){
    struct node nodeToBeInserted;
    *t = &nodeToBeInserted;
    int comparison = compareString(s, nodeToBeInserted.word);
    if(*t == NULL){
        copyString(s, nodeToBeInserted.word);
        nodeToBeInserted.count = 1;
        nodeToBeInserted.length = stringLength(s);
        nodeToBeInserted.left = NULL;
        nodeToBeInserted.right = NULL;

    } else {
        if(comparison < 0){
            insertNode(&nodeToBeInserted.left, s);
        } else if(comparison == 0){
            nodeToBeInserted.count++;
        } else {
            insertNode(&nodeToBeInserted.right, s);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char* buf[MAXCHARS];
    int end = 0;
    struct node* root = NULL;
    insertNode(&root, "hello");
    insertNode(&root, "world");
    printf("%s\n", root -> word);
    printf("%s\n", root -> right -> word);
}
```

The output is then just two blank lines

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the built-in `strcpy()` and `strcmp()`?

Comment: `nodeToBeInserted` is a local variable with automatic scope. It stops existing as soon as the function returns. You need dynamic allocation to create something whose lifetime is independent of the scope where it is created: typically `malloc`

Comment: try a simpler problem first. build it to create a single list but inserts must keep alphabetical order. Once you got that, then the tree is easier.

Comment: @Useless What do I need to change in order to make it work then?

Comment: You should learn how to use the `malloc` function, I suggest reading the documentation and looking at some examples.